# Swift framework is loads in Objective C app on the simulator, but not on device

Tags: swift, ipad, swift2, xcode7, ios-frameworks

Here is the error I get:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/AAA.framework/AAA
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/7250F8A6-E0D8-4BF2-BBD9-F1315D1439F7/BBB.app/BBB
  Reason: image not found
```

- This is built using Xcode 7.3.1.
- I've followed other pieces of advice from other answers.

  - The framework is in "Linked Frameworks and Libraries".
  - The framework is in "Link Binary with Libraries".
  - `LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS` is set to `$(inherited) @executable_path/Frameworks`.
  - `EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT` is `YES`.
  - I've done "Clean Build Folder…", Projects > Derived Data > "Delete…", and rebooted both the Mac and the iPad.
  - Neither Cocoapods or Carthage are used.

Is there anything else I'm missing? I haven't been able to find the answer on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Your app cannot load the framework binary because it has not been copied to your device together with the app. You need to add the `*.framework` file to the `Embed Frameworks` Build phase of your app target. By doing so, the framework will be copied to the `Frameworks` folder inside the app bundle so your app can load it.

**Embedding frameworks**

There are two ways to embed a framework into your app:

1. Using the `General` tab on a target's build settings.
   [image: General Tab]
2. Using the `Build Phases` tab on a target's build settings.
   [image: Build Phases Tab]

*Please note*: If your framework has been added to the `Link Binary with Libraries` Build Phase before it will be added again leaving you with two references to the same framework.

Comment: I believe having the framework in "Link Binary with Libraries" does this. If not, how should I do this?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. It only works the other way around. If you add the framework to the `Embed Frameworks` Build Phase then it'll be added to `Link Binary with Libraries` Build Phase. You need to add it either to aforementioned build phase or you add it via the `General` tab in the target's build settings. I will add some more details and screenshots to my answer for clarification.